# Why is my website available for 2 URL: when I search it with http and https?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, https, java-8

[image: This is google domain view]

[image: This is how it looks on heroku]

If I type www.website.com I end up in the http with the not secure tag.
Instead, if I want to find it with the secure https, I have to search for it as https://www.....com.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure which language you're using to build you website, so I can't answer this exacty. That being said, you need to search for `Secure Proxy SSL Header` and `Secure SSL redirect` : This will help you to redirect request towards https, and more importantly, you'll have just one URL!

Comment: @Ronnie can you please take a look now?

Comment: I read in my notification, that you're using Spring Boot. However, you've deleted that and reconstructed the post as I can see now. I want you to understand that the tags you've mentioned here, are not related to your problem. Your problem is on the application level, i.e. Java and Spring Boot - So you've been searching in the wrong direction all this time.

Comment: Please update your Java and Spring Boot version in the post, to get an accurate answer.

Comment: @Ronnie Now I feel silly :) I am using java 8, with the latest spring boot (in Intelij IDE, if of any help). I will try everything you told me down in the answers and let you know! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already configured your SSL certificate, then it should be a cake walk for you. In any other case [here is a link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl)..

Now, you can redirect HTTP request and enforce the use of HTTPS when your app is running on Heroku by adding the following configuration to your Spring Boot app.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel()
      .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
      .requiresSecure();
  }
}
```

If you already have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation, then add the above configuration to it.

This configuration tells Spring to redirect all plain HTTP requests back to the same URL using HTTPS if the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is present. Heroku sets the X-Forwarded-Proto header for you, which means the request will be redirected back through the Heroku router where SSL is terminated.

Source: Heroku Devcenter

Comment: [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1l8V6FrDG-A) on how to enable SSL to Spring boot applications